# Bar plot causing knit hiccup

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to make bar plots with ggplot in my r-markdown and it works beautifully when I run it as code in the console. But the moment I try to knit the markdown, I get an error saying "Error: ! Must request at least one colour from a hue palette."

Does anyone know how I can attempt to fix this?

This is my code (both plots below won't knit)

```
#Box Plots of Classes Passed
#Plot 1
ggplot(data, aes(y = counts, x = `n of classes passed`, fill = `n of classes passed`)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(.~sy) +
  geom_col()+
    geom_text(aes(label=counts), vjust=1.5, colour="white", size=3.5)+
  labs(y = "Number of Students", title = "courses passed", subtitle= "Among sample students", x = "Courses Passed")

#Plot 2
  ggplot(data, aes(y = counts, x = `n of classes passed`, colour = `n of classes passed`)) +
    geom_segment( aes(xend=`n of classes passed`, yend=0)) +
  facet_wrap(~sy)+
    geom_point( size=4, color="orange") +
  geom_text(aes(label=counts), vjust=0.15, size=2, color="black")+
  coord_flip() +
   theme(aspect.ratio=7/10)+
  labs(x = "Courses Passed", title = "courses passed", subtitle= "Among sample students", y = "Number of Students")
```

This is my entire data set (in dput format):

```
structure(list(sy = c("20-21", "20-21", "20-21", "20-21", "21-22", 
"21-22", "21-22", "21-22", "22-23", "22-23", "22-23", "22-23"
), `n of classes passed` = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("0", "1-5", "6-10", "10 or more"
), class = "factor"), counts = c(27L, 97L, 3L, 12L, 9L, 38L, 
55L, 27L, 11L, 36L, 63L, 43L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Here's a picture of my data set(values have been modified):
[image]

Comment: Instead of adding your data as an image it would be easier to help you, if you share your data it using `dput()`, i.e. run `dput(data)` an copy & paste the output in your post.

Comment: @stefan, Okay! I just updated the post accordingly

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't reproduce your issue. When I put your code and the provided example data in a fresh Rmd it renders fine. From your error message I would guess that the column mapped on fill/color contains only NA (which of course is not the case for your example data), e.g. run `ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = 1, fill = NA))`.

Comment: yeah for some reason, that also doesn't work. I'll keep tinkering with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record: What helped me solve this was by restarting R. Once I did that and ran the code again in the console, all of a sudden I could see where the code was breaking, which is why it wasn't knitting. I fixed the small code mistake (it was like parentheses were missing or something) and then the knit worked fine. My suggestion: Close out R, then open it again, and run your code in the console before knitting to try to find the hiccups in your markdown.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).